# Install yum on a Linux system

Tags: software-installation, yum, rpm, kvm

I have a`Linux` distribution, which does not have `yum` or `dnf`, only `rpm`. Unfortunately, since `rpm` does not manage the packages or resolve dependencies, it implies downloading and installing each dependent package, which is a bit slow.

I thought of installing `yum` on the system, but there are a considerable number of `python3` related dependencies, which runs into a long chain.

Is there a way to get a pre-built, or pre-packaged `yum` distribution which would take care of these individual dependencies and allow a `yum` installation? I got the `tar.gz` package from http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki.html, but I am not aware of what needs to be done with it, or whether it will be sufficient, I can see it uses `py` so I assume a `python` installation is required, however, getting `python` to install is itself quite time intensive.

I needed `yum` to install `kvm` since my system does not have it (most likely), and the list of dependencies to be resolved using `rpm` is quite large...

Comment: Use a popular distribution which already contains kvm.

Comment: which distrib are you using?

Comment: It's called Wind River Linux with sato GUI. Doesn't have a lot inside it.

Comment: `yum` is a `python` module and I do not believe there is an implementation to run it without `python` already installed.  It appears that Wind River Linux is a locked down operating system that does not normally allow installing of new packages.  From what I found from limited searching, you would build a new Wind River Linux image containing the software you want to use, then deploy that image to your device.

Comment: @GracefulRestart I was considering a way to install packages like `kvm` using `yum`, but if `yum` installation is troublesome, or a build with this specified package may not be immediately possible, is there any other, possibly less tedious, way to install `kvm`, other than downloading and installing each dependent package manually using `rpm`? Perhaps an alternative to `yum` which may itself not need other dependent packages?

Comment: I am not sure which version of Wind River Linux you are using, but [according to the documentation for the most recent LTS release](https://docs.windriver.com/bundle/Wind_River_Linux_Tutorial_Creating_KVM_System_Images_LTS_19/page/mmo1403548893878.html) you really have to build a new image with KVM enabled and deploy it to your device.  In my limited research, I also found that the package manager for Wind River Linux is called `smart`, so try using that instead of `yum` to search for and install packages.

Comment: Thank you. I shall try with `smart`. Maybe I can find something in the `Yocto` wiki, or build a new image with KVM enabled.

Comment: @GracefulRestart I managed to get DNF and Py installed, though the packages available with WRinux aren't the full ones. I think I can use what I have to download required packages, but I am not able to configure the repositories. The `dnf.conf` for dnf repo is blank, I followed https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Setting_repository_Options.html, and set https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/30/Everything/source/tree/ as the repo Url, but I may have missed something, since it is unable to find the named packages.

Comment: I managed to set the mirror URL, I was searching for a `repo` which matches  `dnf-4.2.2` which I have installed on my system, Fedora 30 matched that, unfortunately I get a few errors related to conflicts with existing packages etc Seems not very compatible.

Comment: I am curious what rpm distribution does not have yum or dnf?